# Using Auth0 with NestJS on gRPC Methods

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, grpc, grpc-node

I am trying to implement NestJS Guards for Authentication and Authorization to my gRPC Services, which are implemented in NestJS.

```
@GrpcMethod(USER_SERVICE_NAME, 'GetUser')
private getUser(req: GetUserRequest): Promise<GetUserResponse> {
    return this.userService.getUser(req);
}
```

By now I found out how to implement it for regular HTTP requests, following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-getting-started/).
But as far as I can see this gets the JWT from a regular http request.

Now how can I apply that to gRPC requests. I also found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-guard-grpc), but here I am not sure how I would set the cache, rateLimit, and hash-algorithm options.

Comment: My advice would be to not use that package it has a lot of dependencies and barely any subtantial code to warrant adding it to your project.

However, it could serve as an example of how to implement your own guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now how can I apply that to gRPC requests. I also found this package, but here I am not sure how I would set the cache, rateLimit, and hash-algorithm options.

In that package you linked to, you can see in the readme you are expected to implement your own `IAuthService`.

They have provided an example in which they call the `jwt.verify` method using the token provided to the `IAuthService` through the `params` argument.

The JWT token is extracted from the gRPC request's **metadata** as seen [here](https://github.com/mabuonomo/nestjs-guard-grpc/blob/29455b20455074d8caf2e6253e9dec77944d0b27/libs/nestjs-guard-grpc/src/guard/grpc.guard.ts#L25).

You can select the **algorithm** you want to use in the third `options` parameter of the `jwt.verify` function.

```js
// Extract taken from the package's readme.
const options = {
  // For example...
  algorithms: ['HS256', 'HS384']
};

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  jwt.verify(token, getKey, options, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(decoded);
  });
}).then((user) => user);
```

Regarding **cache** I do not know exactly what you mean maybe the `maxAge` option on the `jwt.verify` function?

> **maxAge**: the maximum allowed age for tokens to still be valid. It is
> expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span zeit/ms.

Regarding rate limiting you can probably implement that on top of your `Controller` method using [this example](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting) from the NestJS documentation.